# React js how to trigger css animation when state updated

Tags: css, reactjs

I am wondering how can I trigger css animation when state updated in react js.
I am using 1 div to render the data dynamically in the case while the css animation will only be triggered once.
Do we have any solution for that?

**Simplified code**:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(0);

return(
  <>
    <div className="fade-in">
     <p>{data}</p> // this data will change by some event, I want the css animation to be triggered every time when data changes
    </div>
  </>
)
```

**css**

```css
.fade-in{
  animation: fadein 1100ms;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

I don't really want to make multiple divs to display `data` and to make 1 of them `active` to trigger css driven by event because I want to make the component simple and dynamic.

Comment: have you tried to add ```animation: fadein 1100ms ease-in-out``` ?

Comment: @cantdocpp Yea, actually that didn't work for this case. Even with adding that animation, it would once run once. But I want it to run every time when the `data` changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help!
But I think I may have found the easiest way to do it on my own.
Turns out we can update the `key` of the root component to tell react that this is a totally different component so it will re-render the component.
By which, the css will be triggered again as the entire component has been newly rendered!
The code-wise effort is smallest so I will just go with this approach!

e.g.

```js
  const [data, setData] = useState(0);

  const handleOnChange = () => {
    setDate(Math.random());
  }

  return(
    <>
      {/*set key for this root div*/}
      <div className="fade-in" key={data}>
       <p>{data}</p>
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleOnChange}>update</button>
    </>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add more stage and one useEffect to track when your stage change. Your code should be:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(0);
const [change, setChange] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
const changeStage = () => {
setChange(true);
setTimeout(() => {
  setChange(false);
}, 1100); // Adjust the timeout duration equal to your animation time, in your case is 1100
};
changeStage()
},[data])

return(
  <>
    <div className={change?"fade-in":""}>
     <p>{data}</p> // this data will change by some event, I want the css animation to be triggered every time when data changes
    </div>
  </>
)
```

Comment: Thank you @thangmechancial very much for your answer and efforts, your solution works as well but I just figured out an easier way to do it. Sorry please forgive me to accept mine for this question.